# I have no idea how to do this? i am trying to use Boyle's law, but I can't

Tags: ideal-gas

so we have crockery with 0.5-litre volume, in this crockery is water of 0.3 litres. how many litre waters can we pour out, if air mustn't go in. after this pour pressure will be 80kpa.

Comment: What is the material in the vapor space of the pottery, what is the initial temperature, initial pressure, and final temperature?  You can probably use the ideal gas law, but you need a lot more information.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not stated very clearly.

I presume initially there is air in the pot at atmospheric pressure, and water is added with no addition of air.  I assume the water added is at the same temperature as the water initially in the pot. You can use the ideal gas law to determine the amount of water added to increase the pressure of the initial amount of air to the given final pressure.  A more detailed evaluation would also consider the partial pressure of the water vapor.